# Can I get the name of a method by providing the method itself?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5

Is there a way to get a method's name (as a string) by providing the method itself?

```
class Person
{
    bool Eat(Food food){...}
}
```

I want to somehow get the string "Eat". That's all! This can either be from an instance or from the class declaration using reflection.

My attempt:

```
public delegate bool EatDelegate(Food f);

EatDelegate eatDel = new EatDelegate(_person1.Eat);
string methodName = eatDel.GetInvocationList()[0].Method.Name;
```

This requires to know the method's delegate and the whole thing is unreadable

I want the methodName in order to dynamically invoke it.

Notes:

- There is a delegate declaration for every method I want to invoke
- I want to avoid specifying the method's name in order to avoid errors after reflection etc
- The method isn't called the moment I want to get its name. (cannot use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` )
- I have to use .Net 3.5

Comment: Could probably work something out with expressions...

Answer (score 5):

```
public string GetName(Expression<Action> exp)
{
    var mce = exp.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    return mce.Method.Name;
}
```

--

a Method

```
public int  MyMethod(int i)
{
    return 0;
}
```

and usage

```
 var s= GetName(()=>this.MyMethod(0));
```

Comment: Will this run the method once?

Answer (score 0):

```
var methods = typeof(Person).GetMethods();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    if (method.Name.Equals("Eat"))
    {
         // do something here...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I want to avoid. To have to specify the "Eat" string value.

Comment: From question: _"I want to somehow get the string "Eat". That's all!"_ **and** _"I want to avoid specifying the method's name"_

Comment: Exactly. As you can see in L.B.s answer this is done using the instance of the object.